# Prove that $22\ldots 22$ ($1980$ twos) $\equiv 0 \pmod{1982}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

> Prove that $$\underbrace{22\ldots 22}_{1980} \equiv  0 \pmod{1982}$$

I tried and found that we need to prove that $991$ divides  $\underbrace{11\ldots 11}_{1980}$. I am stuck after this.

Comment: The usual way to deal with _repdigits_ is to realize that $222\cdots 2 = 2(111\cdots 1) = \frac{2}{9}(999\cdots 9) = \frac{2}{9}(10^{1980}-1).$

Comment: I did not get the last equal to.

Comment: Oh! I got it and wrote it, but after that?

Comment: Yeah, $\underbrace{99\ldots 99}_{1980}=10^{1981}-1$.

Comment: hmmm, after that?

Comment: $10^{990}\equiv 1 \pmod {1982}$

Comment: yes, hmm, written

Comment: Would anyone give me a full answer? I will be grateful to you.

Answer (score 2):

$991$ is prime so $10^{990} \equiv 1 \mod 991$

So $10^{1980} = (10^{990})^2 \equiv 1 \mod 991$

So $991| 10^{1980}-1 = 99999...... = 9*11111.....$ and $\gcd (9,991) = 1$ so $991 | 111111.....$ so $1982| 222222.......= \frac {10^{1980} - 1}9 * 2$.

Answer (score 1):

$\underbrace{22\ldots 22}_{1980} = \frac {2}{9}\sum_\limits {i=0}^{1979} 10^i = \frac {2}{9} (10^{1980} -1)$

$10^{990}\equiv 1 \pmod {991}$ by Fermat's little theorem.

$10^{1980} = (10^{990})^2\equiv 1^2 \pmod {991}$

$10^{1980} - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {991}\\
(10^{1980} - 1) \equiv 0 \pmod {991}$

$\frac 19(10^{1980} - 1)$ is whole number.

$991$ is prime and $991|9\cdot \frac 19(10^{1980} - 1)$ and  implies $991|9$ or $991| \frac 19(10^{1980} - 1)$

If $991$ divides $\frac {1}{9}(10^{1980} - 1), 1982$ divides $\frac {2}{9}(10^{1980} - 1)$

Comment: Check the second congruence, please. How could an even number ($10^{990}$) and an odd number ($1$) be congruent modulo an even modulus ($1982$)???

Comment: Yes, $10^{990} \equiv 992 \mod 1982$. Totient function of 1982 is 992 (991 even numbers and 1 odd number (991)). 10 and 1982 aren't coprime.

Comment: This is the right idea but you are being sloppy. 2222 ne 2(10^1981 - 1).  222== 2*(10^1981 - 1)/9.  10^990 = 1 mod 991 implies either 2*10^990 = 2 \mod 1982 or 10^990 = 1; 991 + 1 \mod 1982 (and as 10^990 and 1982 are even it must but 10^990 = 992.  So 10^1980 = 992^2 = 991^2 + 2*991 + 1^2 = 1 mod 1982. 2(10^1980 -1) = 0 mod 1982 but 2(10^1980 -1)/9 requires showing 9*t = 0 mod 1982 has no solution.  (which isn't hard.)